# Meaning of number in "Error detected while processing function foo#bar[3]"

Tags: vimscript, error

When vim produces an error message like,

```
Error detected while processing function foo#bar[3]
```

what's the significance of the number in square brackets (e.g. 3 in the above example).

The actual error I'm looking at is:

```
Error detected while processing function fzf#vim#files[15]..<SNR>79_fzf[21]..fzf#run[63]..<SNR>17_execute_term[95]..BufDelete Autocommands for "*":
```

My first guess was that it indicated a line number relative to the start of the function, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Next, I thought it was the number of lines contained by the body of the function, but after looking at a couple examples, I'm not sure that's the case either.

Comment: It actually *is* the line number relative to the start of the function. Why do you say *"but that doesn't seem to be the case"*? Can you explain why you got to that conclusion? For instance, the 15th line of `fzf#vim#files()` is the last line of that function, which is a `return s:fzf(...)` and then function `s:fzf()` has 21 lines and the last line is `return fzf#run(...)` and then following `fzf#run()`, line 63 (in the middle of the body) is `return s:execute_term(...)` so there you go... Please [edit] to explain why you thought that was not the case.